# Jquery, find next table on previus table click, used find(), parent(), next()

Tags: jquery

This is the HTML:

```
<table id="head" class="head"><tr><td>FIND CONTENT </td> </tr></table>
<table id="content" class="content"> <tr><td>I HOLD CONTENT</td></tr> </table>
```

This is jQuery function, and everything i have tried, non of those alerts are showing content only undefined, and i need to add a class to that next table

```
$(".head").mouseup(function () {
    alert(this.id);
    alert($(this).next(".content").id);
    alert($(this).next("table").id);

    alert($(this).parent().siblings('table').id)
    alert($(this).closest('table').next(':has(.class):content').find('.class').id);

    alert($(this).closest( ".content" ).id);
    alert($(this).parents().next("table").id);
    alert($(this).parent().parent().parent().next().find(".content").id);
    alert($(this).parent().next().find('.content').id);  
    alert($(this).parent().next('.content').id);  
    alert($(this).parent().next(".content").id);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `id` property of the DOM element *in* the [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/). You are trying to retrieve the `id` property *of* the jQuery object (which is a collection composed of DOM elements).

You could get the first DOM element in the jQuery object:

```
$(this).next(".content")[0].id
```

or you could use the [`.prop()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to retrieve the property:

```
$(this).next(".content").prop('id');
```